# JavaFx Resize VBox as contents are added with ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scrollpane, vbox

I am relatively new to JavaFx and I need help in getting a Vbox to grow as nodes are added to it.

I've place a VBox in a ScrollPane. The VBox gets filled with TitledPanes as they come in. But once the TitledPanes fill the space allotted the Vbox, the TitledPanes begin to overlap. Ideally I would want to Vbox to resize itself and use the ScrollPane to navigate.

I have the Vbox Max Height set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. I've added a listener to the ScrollPane to listen to changes in size of the VBox but no luck. Any Suggestions?

```
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        vBox.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make us able to reproduce. Normally (if you do not use any constraints) if you put a `VBox` inside a `ScrollPane` the `VBox` starts to grow as more and more children are added and the `ScrollPane` displays its scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are using a `VBox` rather than an `Accordion`?
With an `Accordion` you could use a `ListChangeListener` to check for changes in `TitledPane` number and then adjust the size of the `Accordion` if an item was added or removed:

```
accordion.getPanes().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
     public void onChanged(Change<tem> c) {
         while (c.next()) {
             if(c.wasAdded() || c.wasRemoved){
                 //resize Accordion in dependency of the vvalue of your scrollpane
             }
         }
     });
```

For a `VBox`, the principle should still be valid:

```
vbox.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
     public void onChanged(Change<tem> c) {
         while (c.next()) {
             if(c.wasAdded() || c.wasRemoved){
                 //rezise VBox in dependency of the vvalue of your scrollpane
             }
         }
     });
```

[based on](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I was using a VBox because it allows me to have multiple TitledPanes opened at the same time. The ScrollPane was being added to a Anchor Pane inside a SplitPane. Turns out that this does allow the VBox to grow. Adding the ScrollPane Directly to my SplitPane did the trick. Thanks.